# power bi: turn off the report header without changing the report link

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I want to achieve 2 conditions:

1. drop the header from power bi report
   [image]

2) send a link to the report to my subscribers via e-mail

I found how to drop the header. We need to add a parameter to the end of the report link.
http://YourReportServer/Reports/powerbi/YourPowerBIReport?rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false

But I didn't find, how to automatically add the parameter to end of the link during e-mail subscription.

This is why I re-open my question:
Is there a method to drop the report header without changing the link.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you looked at embedding a report?

Comment: Data Monger, thank you for responce. I read something here about embedding, but didn't understand what to do. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Will-the-report-URL-link-change/td-p/142573. I have a report (not a dashboard). I don't have a SharePoint portal to embed to. Where to embed a report and how it can help with links?

Comment: Check if you have https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/service-get-started

and try and publishing a report from your desktop to the service.

Comment: Data Monger, thank you for advice, but the link describes dashboards, but I don't want to organise my report into dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish the report to Power BI service and embed the report like so

[image]